# regular expression: Find url from anchor tag

Tags: php, regex

i have problem .
i want to find out the url form acnchor tag which consist "title" tag in anchor tag.

```
example:
<a href="http://www.test.com" title="xyz">this is test</a>
```

how can i match the string and fetch url using regular expression.

thanks

Comment: What language are you using (.NET, Java, JavaScript, PERL, Python something else)? RegEx implementations differ in different languages, so this is essential to answering the question. You should also let us know if you are simply have this type of string, or whole HTML documents.

Comment: in the future, use _all_ the tags that apply to the question. You have up to 5 tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<a\s+([^>]*)href="(https?:\/\/([^"]*))"\s+([^>]*)title="xyz"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>` you can get the url by partial match `$2`, you can try it [here](http://www.regextester.com/index2.html)

Comment: Note that attribute values can contain plain `>` characters.

Comment: true, but thats good right? because it wont stop matching urls until it hits a " because of this `[^"]*`

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I would use an HTML parsing library to just get the contents of the `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

`/href="(.*?)(?=".*?title)/`

you will have to trim the `href="` from the beginning of the match

`/abc(?=xyz)/` positive lookahead -> matches `abc` if `abc` is followed by `xyz`