# Regex to match any url in img tag

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression that can match any url in img src tag

URL can vary from "/images/temp.jpg" or "temp1.jpg" or even "http://www.example.com/temp.jpg?i=123" or anything

I have written following code:

```
preg_match_all('/(href|src)\s*=\s*"([^\s]+\/\/[^\/]+.\/[^\s]+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp))/ixu'
```

but it's not matching many urls including those with query string like ?i=12345

Anyone have idea how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [regular expression: Find url from anchor tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351276/regular-expression-find-url-from-anchor-tag)

Comment: @Dan: I tried, but it's not working in my case

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
<img [^>]*src="([^"]+)"
```

and take the first capturing group.

**EDIT:** By the way this assumes that you would not start a tag without properly closing it. Perhaps better is

```
<img [^>]*src="([^"]+)"[^>]*>
```

**EDIT 2:** It is unclear what you are trying to achieve, and I get the feeling I am wasting my time trying to help you. In your edit, you wrote that you tried:

```
preg_match_all('/(href|src)\s*=\s*"([^\s]+\/\/[^\/]+.\/[^\s]+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp))/ixu'
```

Why is there no mention of img? Why do you include href, when img tags do not take the href attribute? It seems as though you are more interested in checking whether something is a valid image URL than in matching some URL that is specified inside an img tag. Note that the regex I provided does not check the validity of the URL; it just goes based on the fact that whatever appears in quotes in the src attribute is expected to be a valid URL. I did it this way because it is a practical assumption in many situations, and you weren't specific about what you really want. I will not update further if you can't ask a better question.

Comment: please explain what is first capture group

Comment: @I-M-JM Sorry, I had a typo, the correct term is capturing group. This is basic regex stuff, you can find out everything you need to know from a google search. You use parentheses `()` to specify capturing groups.

Answer (score 1):

Search first, asked and answered hundreds of times over the years:

[regular expression: Find url from anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351276/regular-expression-find-url-from-anchor-tag)

Just replace `<a` with `<img` and `href` with `src`