# Need regular expression for string access

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a huge string. The string is in the following form :

```
  var str =  "content.....
              more content.........
              <script src='url' ... />
              <script src='url' ... />
              <script src='url' ... />
              ....
              .........";
```

Now i want to access all the urls from the string. So for this i am using the following javascript :

```
    var regex = //this part i required
    var matches = [];
    var match = regex.exec(str);
```

Can anyone please give me the regular expression to access all the values of the src from the above string ?

Comment: No need to use regex for this, better would be to parse your string in a jquery object. See dystroy's answer

Comment: This one is for PHP, but what you need should be very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436108/regex-to-match-any-url-in-img-tag

Answer (score 4):

You're importing jQuery, so, supposing your string is valid HTML, you can use it to parse it and get your URL.

It turns out that it's not so easy, as jQuery doesn't let you find `<script>` elements.

I made this solution but it's clearly not very elegant :

```
str = str.replace(/script/g, 'placeholder');
var urls = $('placeholder', '<div>'+str+'</div>').map(
    function(){return $(this).attr('src')}
).get();
```

This makes an array containing all your urls.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/pq45P/)